# Get the number of pages in a chapter

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

Is there any way to call up the number of pages in a given chapter? I'm using the `\chapter` command to separate chapters, and I want to be able to write something like:

```
Chapter 1 has [number of pages] pages in it.
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Text...
\chapter{Chapter 2}
Text...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to load `hyperref`, you can use `refcount` instead.  You can use the `lastpage` package to get the length of the last chapter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}% defines \getpagerefnumber
\begin{document}
Chapter 1 has [\the\numexpr\getpagerefnumber{c2}-\getpagerefnumber{c1}\relax] pages in it.
\chapter{Chapter 1}\label{c1}

Text...
\chapter{Chapter 2}\label{c2}
Text...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately the chapter whose page count I need is not the last chapter (it's actually near the middle of the document).

Comment: Which makes it easier, not harder.